# Android App Gradient Background

Tags: android, android-layout, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am developing an Android app using MonoDevelop and I have a table with 12 ImageButtons that are 48x48.  The table is centered in the android screen.  I cannot figure out how to put a gradient background, or any background, behind the table.

Is it possible to place a view behind the table or maybe I should be using a different control other than a table.... maybe a GridView?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried one of the following in you Table Layout?

XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/cool_gradient"
```

In code:

```
tableLayout.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.cool_gradient);
```

Where "cool_gradient" is a .xml file with your gradient in your "Resources/Drawable" folder. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#E8E8E8" 
        android:endColor="#BEBEBE"
        android:angle="270"
     />
</shape>
```